# To find difference between two integer fields and check it falls under a specific range, using scripts in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two fields,let us name them "fieldA" and "fieldB" in my documents and i need to find the difference between them and check if that value falls under a specific range say "rangeA" or " rangeB" and then return the documents that matches my criteria.
The schema for data is as shown below:

```
{
"fieldA": 45
"fieldB":13
}
```

I need to find all the document which have the difference between "fieldA" and "fieldB" in between 30 and 35. How can i do this using scripting in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can also be done using aggregations and scripts like below:

```
{
   "aggregations": {
      "age_diff": {
         "range": {
            "script": "doc[\"fieldA\"].value - doc[\"fieldB\"].value",
            "ranges": [
               {
                  "from": 30,
                  "to": 35
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This way you can just check how many documents falls under the specified range.But if you want to get the documents under the aggregations you can use "top_hits" aggregations.

More detailed discussion on aggregations can be found [here](http://blog.qbox.io/elasticsearch-aggregations) and more about "top_hits" can be found in detail [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "difference=doc['fieldA'].value-doc['fieldB'].value;return (difference>param1 && difference<param2);",
          "params": {
            "param1":30,
            "param2":35
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```